# Nesting functions and generating a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to plot the spatial response of a given beamformer `w` as a function of the direction `theta` of a source with array response `a(theta)`, i.e.

```
function y = spat_response(w,Delta,theta_range)
```

Note that this is given by `|y(t)|=|w^{H}a(theta)|`, with `w^{H}` denoting the complex conjugate transpose of `w`.

For `a(theta)`, I already have:

```
function a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta)
    for m=1:M
        a(m)=exp(1i*2*pi*Delta*sin(theta)*(m-1));
    end
end
```

For plotting the spatial response `|y(t)|`, I have been unsuccessful and this is what I've contrived so far:

```
function y = spat_response(w,Delta,theta_range)
y(t) = abs(w'*a(theta_range));
a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta);
            function a = gen_a(M,Delta;theta)
                for m=1:M
                    a(m)=exp(1i*2*pi*Delta*sin(theta)*(m-1));
                end    
            end
fplot(y,[-25,25])        
end
```

The nesting isn't working though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest the functions.

```
function y = spat_response(w,Delta,theta_range)
  a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta);
  y(t) = abs(w'*a(theta_range));        
  fplot(y,[-25,25])        
end

function a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta)
    for m=1:M
        a(m)=exp(1i*2*pi*Delta*sin(theta)*(m-1));
    end
end
```

You will only be able to call `spat_response()` from outside the `.m`, the other functions will be available only on the `.m` scope

Comment: I see. But I am still getting errors with my definition (or lack of) 'theta_range' and also my definition of the function y(t).

Comment: `y(t)` makes no sense inside the spat_response, as you have no `t`, try `y = abs(w'*a(theta_range))`.

Comment: The problem is also that 'a' is not properly defined as one can even see on StackOverflow, where your text turns red after the introduction of 'a'. Defining theta_range is also something that hasn't been done and I am stuck at.

Comment: without providing definitions for thetha, thetha_range, and Delta, it's impossible to help you further than this.

Comment: theta and Delta are the variables of the function a; all of which work perfectly fine in my 'gen_a(M, Delta, theta)' function. And 'theta_range' I want to define such that I get a value for all 'theta' in a certain range, say 0 to 2pi.